# Android way to add new xml layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an activity with a layout. After a GET request to a server, I want to dynamically add new elements to that layout.

I want to add those elements multiple times, using a for-structure.

The elements I want to add are the following:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@drawable/outer_border"
            android:padding="2dp" 
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/orange"
                android:height="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="TW"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="70px"
                android:width="60dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:text="inca 6 zile"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < homeworkList.size(); i++){
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

    RelativeLayout newLayout = new RelativeLayout(currentActivity, null, R.style.HomeworkLayout);

    TextView text = new TextView(currentActivity);
    TextView text1 = new TextView(currentActivity);
    text1.setText("da");
    text.setText("nu");

    newLayout.addView(text1);
    newLayout.addView(text);

    linearLayout.addView(newLayout, relativeParams);
    }
```

But no result, those textview were added but on top of each other, and the relative layout I just added in that for doesn't have any of the style I added using R.style.HomeworkLayout.

**What is the best way to add the elements with so much styling? Why isn't this working?**

Answer (score 2):

> those textview were added but on top of each other

That's what you told `RelativeLayout` to do. If you wanted to specify positioning rules, you would have passed instances of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to `addView()` when you were adding the `TextView` widgets.

> What is the best way to add the elements with so much styling?

Well, probably, the answer is to use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. That being said, the simplest solution that keeps your vertical `LinearLayout` would be to inflate the rows:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) currentActivity.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

for(int i = 0; i < homeworkList.size(); i++){
    View row=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, linearLayout, false);

    // call findViewById() to retrieve your TextView widgets and fill them in

    linearLayout.addView(row);
}
```

This assumes that the layout you show in your question is named `R.layout.row`; adjust the `inflate()` call as needed if that is not the name. This also assumes that the code snippet is in a method on the activity that is hosting this UI.

Comment: Sounds nice. But if I use the same R.layout.row 5 times, how should I retrieve my TextViews if they all have tha same ID in  the template?

Comment: @CrazyDog: Call `row.findViewById()`, not `findViewById()`. That will retrieve the widgets with the desired name in `row`, versus from the whole activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a layout which is repeating why don't you prefer using a custom liner layout.

A simple and basic solution is mentioned on this link 
http://android-coding-tuts.blogspot.in/2012/02/custom-listview-with-sliding-view-for.html

Comment: Could you please explain the relative part instead of adding tutorial link alone? Links are not 100% reliable and link may not work in future due to some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up Fragments for this. They have a separate control-view structure and you can just create a new fragment for each subview.

Check it out here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html